# Unable to add the value of two input fields

Tags: javascript

I am not able to add the value of two input fields with an onclick event.
I´ve received all different kinds of errors. The last error i get is "TypeError: document.getelementById is not a function
Line: 8"

This is the code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>calculadora</title>
    <script>
        function eventsumar(num1, num2) {
        var x = document.getelementById("num1");
        var y = document.getelementById("num2");
        var z = x + y; 
        };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form> 
             <input type="number" id="num1">
             <strong>+</strong>
             <input type="number" id="num2">
             <button type="button" onclick=eventsumar(num1, num2) value="Sumar">sumar</button>
             <strong>=</strong>
        </form>
        <p id="resu"></p>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Case matters in Javascript, it's getElementById not getelementById

Comment: Why are you (trying) to pass parameters you don't even use?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems in the code .

- `document.getElementById` is case sensitive. `document.getelementById` will not work.
- `document.getElementById` will return the reference object to that Id. You need to add `.value` to read the value.
- Their is no need to pass variables inside function.. You are reading them from the function itself.

```js
        function eventsumar() {
        var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
         var z = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y); 
        document.getElementById("resu").innerText = z;
       
        };
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>calculadora</title>
   
    </head>
    <body>
        <form> 
             <input type="number" id="num1">
             <strong>+</strong>
             <input type="number" id="num2">
             <button type="button" onclick="eventsumar()" value="Sumar">sumar</button>
             <strong>=</strong>
 <p id="resu"></p>
        </form>
       
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Yourdaman click on `Run Code Snippet` enter values and click submit.

Comment: great, i figured it out